# When using devise gem what happens when user click on Confirm my Account on email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I was wondering that what happens in the backend when user click to Confirm my Account on his email to confirm his account. Because before clicking on the link on email when i check **User.last** on console it shows the user details but user can't "sign in" until he click the link on email.

I have to send the email to the user when he click the Confirm my Account link on his email with a welcome message for the website.

Currently the email has sent if the user does'nt click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Devise to only allow users with confirmed email addresses to be able to sign in by using [`confirmable`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb).

When Devise in configured to only allowed confirmed users to log in then these things happen:

1. User signs up.
2. Devise sends an email to the user with a unique `confirmation_token`.
3. When the user clicks that link, Devise searches for the user by that `confirmation_token`. And
4. Devise sets `confirmed_at` on that user.

Because the user's `confirmed_at` attribute is now set, Devise will allow this user logging in from now on.

For further details, see the comments in the source code of [`confirmable`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb).